# how to remove smart quotes in copy/paste?

Tags: emacs, copy-paste

I'm copying text from either Google Chrome or PDFs, and pasting into Emacs.

The original text has smart quotes. I don't want smart quotes in the output.

Is there a way, either on the Copying side or on the Pasting side, to automatically strip out the smart quotes?

Comment: [Emacswiki function to do this for all sorts of non-ascii characters](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplaceGarbageChars)

Comment: The same problem occurs when copying from various text editors on OS X when the "use smart quotes" system preference is enabled.  Specifically, I encountered this when copying from Evernote to a web form, which then stripped all the "smart" quote marks and apostrophes completely.  The accepted answer provided a neat intermediate step to solve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
(defun replace-smart-quotes (beg end)
  "Replace 'smart quotes' in buffer or region with ascii quotes."
  (interactive "r")
  (format-replace-strings '(("\x201C" . "\"")
                            ("\x201D" . "\"")
                            ("\x2018" . "'")
                            ("\x2019" . "'"))
                          nil beg end))
```

Put that in your `~/.emacs` and you should be able to use <kbd>M-x replace-smart-quotes</kbd> to fix all quotes in the current buffer or selected region.

To avoid restarting Emacs for the `~/.emacs` change to take effect, move your cursor to the end of the `defun` with <kbd>M-C-e</kbd> and evaluate it <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd>.

**Update** re comment:

To automatically do this when yanking (pasting), you could do something like the following:

```
(defun yank-and-replace-smart-quotes ()
  "Yank (paste) and replace smart quotes from the source with ascii quotes."
  (interactive)
  (yank)
  (replace-smart-quotes (mark) (point)))
```

If you then want to do that when you hit <kbd>C-y</kbd>, you can bind it using:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-y") 'yank-and-replace-smart-quotes)
```

It's probably a better idea to use another key however (maybe <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd>) as this will use some of the default `yank` functionality.

Comment: Thanks. But what about a function that will strip the quotes out during copy/paste? Kind of like "Paste and Match Formatting" with stripping out smart quotes.

Comment: You can do that too, I've added an example. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://readingworldmagazine.com/emacs/2020-02-20-emacs-enter-exit-appearance/

```
(defun replace-garbage-chars ()
"Replace non-rendering MS and other garbage characters with latin1 equivalents."
(interactive)
(save-excursion             ;save the current point
(replace-string "\221" "`" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\222" "'" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\226" "-" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\227" "--" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\223" "(" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\224" ")" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\205" "..." nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\225" "-" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\344" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\374" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\337" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\366" "" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\247" "***" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\267" "****" nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\351" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\347" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\352" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\342" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\307" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\340" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\340" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\364" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\353" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-string "\243" " " nil (point-min) (point-max))
));end replace-garbage-characters
;bind-key replace-garbage-characters
(bind-key  "\C-cr"  'replace-garbage-chars)
```